# Configuração do PHP CodeSniffer no VSCode

Tags: php, composer, visual-studio-code, psr

Não estou conseguindo configurar a extensão phpcs no vscode.

**O que já fiz**

- Já baixei e instalei o composer
- Instalei a extensão phpcs no vscode

Estou desde sedo tentando configurar isso. Quando  escrevo qualquer linha de código, aparece uma mensagem no canto inferior direito:

> "phpcs: Request workspace/configuration failed with message: Unable to
>   locate phpcs. Please add phpcs to your global path or use composer
>   dependency manager to install it in your project locally."

**O que queria**

Queria utilizar o phpcs em um pasta específica de um projeto!

**P.S:** aposto que é algo extremamente simples e eu estou apanhando atoa!

Comment: Você utilizou o argumento *global* quando instalou via composer?

Comment: sim, esse aqui: *composer require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"

Comment: Use `composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"` ou informe o *path* na configuração do *plugin* `phpcs.executablePath`

Comment: fiz e continua pedindo para configurar

Comment: Usa qual sistema operacional?

Comment: passo raiva com o windows, quero dizer, uso windows

Comment: @LucasInácio Já tentou indicar o local de instalação nas variáveis de ambientes no Windows? https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/